# Digital Ocean Kubernetes Node scale -> 503

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, digital-ocean, horizontal-scaling

I'm running a rails container in a digital ocean kubernetes cluster with a horizontal pod autoscaler.
Sometimes when our nodes are scaled, customers encounter 503s.

- When the replica count is increased but the node count stays the same this does not happen.
- I have set the readiness probe to a quite high value (30s) and as I said the scheduling of new pods in general seems to work without errors.

Has anyone seen this behaviour or maybe solved it?

Any help or hints would be appreciated.